# Error al Insertar datos a una tabla en PostgreSQL con Java Netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, postgresql, netbeans-8.2

Tengo una tabla con los campos: id_venta, fecha, nombre y direccion; de los cuales el nombre y la direccion son puestos en la pagina web, para poder registrar la venta, el usuario anota su nombre y dirección y al momento de enviar el codigo debe asignarle un id_venta y la fecha de acuerdo a su ordenador; entonces al momento de enviar aparece el error de Null, para los campos de id_venta y dirección.

Les dejo el código que use para dichos registros, gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import pe.escueladigital.excepciones.ExcepcionGeneral;
import pe.escueladigital.modelos.Producto;
import pe.escueladigital.modelos.VentaDetalle;
import pe.escueladigital.modelos.VentaEncabezado;

public class PSQLVenta {

private final String ENCABEZADO = "INSERT INTO ventas_encabezado (nombre, direccion) VALUES (?,?) RETURNING id_venta, fecha, nombre, direccion";
private final String DETALLE = "INSERT INTO ventas_detalle (id_venta_encabezado, id_producto, id_talla, valor) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";

private Connection conexion;
private PreparedStatement sentencia;
private ResultSet resultados;

public VentaEncabezado insertarVenta(String nombre, String direccion, List<Producto> carro)
            throws ExcepcionGeneral {
    VentaEncabezado encabezado = null;
    try {
        encabezado = insertaEncabezado(nombre, direccion);
        insertaDetalle(carro, encabezado);
    } catch (ExcepcionGeneral eg) {
        throw new ExcepcionGeneral("Error al insertar ventas: "+eg.getMessage());
    }
    return encabezado;
}

private VentaEncabezado insertaEncabezado(String nombre, String direccion) throws ExcepcionGeneral {
    VentaEncabezado encabezado = null;
    try {
        conexion = new PSQLConexion().conectar();
        sentencia = conexion.prepareStatement(ENCABEZADO);
        sentencia.setString(1, nombre);
        sentencia.setString(2, direccion);
        resultados = sentencia.executeQuery();
        if (resultados.next()) {
            encabezado = new VentaEncabezado();
            encabezado.setId(resultados.getInt("id_venta"));
            encabezado.setFecha(resultados.getDate("fecha").toLocalDate());
            encabezado.setNombre(resultados.getString("nombre"));
            encabezado.setDireccion(resultados.getString("direccion"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        throw new ExcepcionGeneral("Error al insertar El encabezado de venta: "+sqle.getMessage());
    } finally {
        cerrarRecursos();
    }
    return encabezado;
}

private void insertaDetalle(List<Producto> carro, VentaEncabezado encabezado) throws ExcepcionGeneral {
    try {
        conexion = new PSQLConexion().conectar();
        sentencia = conexion.prepareStatement(DETALLE);
        for (Producto producto : carro) {

            VentaDetalle detalle = new VentaDetalle();
            detalle.setIdEncabezado(encabezado.getId());
            detalle.setProducto(producto);

            sentencia.setInt(1, detalle.getIdEncabezado());
            sentencia.setShort(2, detalle.getProducto().getId());
            sentencia.setShort(3, detalle.getProducto().getTalla().getId());
            sentencia.setFloat(4, detalle.getProducto().getValor());
            sentencia.executeUpdate();
            encabezado.addDetalle(detalle);
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        throw new ExcepcionGeneral("Error al insertar El detalle de venta: "+sqle.getMessage());
    } finally {
        cerrarRecursos();
    }
}

private void cerrarRecursos() {
    try {
        if (resultados != null) {
            resultados.close();
        }
        if (sentencia != null) {
            sentencia.close();
        }
        if (conexion != null) {
            conexion.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {}
}
```

}

Comment: Ya lo resolví gracias de todos modos :D

Comment: Y cual fue el problema

Comment: en la llamada a la base de datos cambie el código un poquito y funcionó.